# How to get PostSharp to log aspect caught exceptions to a rolling text file vs. the event log

Tags: event-log, postsharp, event-listener

I have googled mush, and found nothing, so please bare with a possible silly question. I have my own logging, of events and stats, that logs to the Event Log. I would like to log long and verbose error information to a 30 day rolling text file. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

To log with PostSharp you can either use included [Diagnostics Pattern Library](http://doc.postsharp.net/diagnostics-library) or create your own custom aspect.

The diagnostics library can log the names of methods being invoked together with parameter/return values. The actual logging messages are sent to one of the supported logging back-ends (Console, System.Diagnostics.Trace, Log4Net, NLog, EnterpriseLibrary).

You can follow the PostSharp docs to add logging with the chosen back-end first, and then you would need to set up that back-end to write messages to a rolling text file. The configuration depends on the specific back-end, there are examples for [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html), [NLog](https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/File-target), etc.

If you want to write more custom information to the log, then it would be better to create your own logging aspect. You can start with the [example in the PostSharp docs](http://doc.postsharp.net/example-trace). Again it would be better to prepare your message and then just pass it on to the logging library that will handle writing to the rolling text file. That way you get the powerful configuration options provided by the library and don't need to re-implement low-level details.